# What is the logical structure of multiple @media queries?

Tags: css

I'm not sure I understand the logic of @media conditions, what would be an **AND** statment and what would be **OR**?

how would I write a condition like this:

```
if ((condition 1 & condition 3) or (condition 2 & condition 3))
```

in a @media query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media types are (separated by commas) of a set of rules (delimited by curly braces)

So you would write you above statement:

```
body { background: green; }
@media screen and (max-width:300px), screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Here's a live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/davetayls/tFXWu/